# Indexing and searching special characters like '@','#' in lucene

Tags: lucene

I am indexing fields using `StandardAnlyzer` which removes punctuations from the input string. My input string contains special characters like `@`, `#` , `-`, etc.

Eg: The indexed data may consist of values like userid: `AB@234`, `ABC#DF`

I am trying to update the index passing BooleanQuery uesrid: `ABC@34` to delete previous documents  using `writer.deletedocuments(query);`
 and the update the index using `writer.updateDocuments(Term,document);`

Deleting the current indexex using above query delete all the values that starts with `ABC@`.i.e, the documents with userid values `ABC@123`, `ABC@55`, etc. are also deleted.

Could any one suggest a solution to index and update specific document containing above special characters.

Any suggession is highly appreciated.

Thank in advance.

Chakradhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is probably to use [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.html) to index your `userid` field and then use [IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(Term)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#deleteDocuments%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term%29) to delete documents.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggession. I have indexed userid field as NOT_ANALYZED and used KetWordAnalyzer for searching the term. And it worked.

Comment: The soultion works when I use KeyWordAnalyzer for searching the indexes. Is there a way to index the userid field with StandardAnalyzer and still search the index using keyWordAnalyzer or any other analyzer that indexes special characters

Comment: The main reason that I am asking for StandardAnalyzer is because it allows pass wildcard queries. Whereas KeyWordAnalyzer doesnot allow wildcard search.

Comment: Maybe you should use different analyzers per field, eg. using http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html